# Google Sheets error in nested if situation

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to have a sheet check scores compared to a grading scale. This is what I have as an argument but I cannot get it to work. Am I missing parenthesis? Some other formatting issue?

=IF(E3<67.9,6.5,IF(E3<71.9),7,IF(E3<76.9),7.5,if(E3<81.9),8, if(E3<85.9),8.5,if(E3<89.9),9,IF(E3<94.9),9.5,10)

I have tried many versions of this same formula but cannot get it to work as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(E3<67.9,6.5,IF(E3<71.9,7,IF(E3<76.9,7.5,if(E3<81.9,8, if(E3<85.9,8.5,if(E3<89.9,9,IF(E3<94.9,9.5,10)))))))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(E3, {0,6.5; 68,7; 72,7.5; 77,8; 82,8.5; 86,9; 90,9.5; 95,10}, 2)
```